# How does SVG opacity stack?

Tags: svg, opacity

I'm wondering, how do SVG elements stack their opacity? More specifically, if I have an element with `opacity: 0.4`, what will the overlapping element's opacity need to be in order to result in `opacity: 0.8` at the overlap?

What is the resulting opacity at the overlap?
https://jsfiddle.net/HZr7v/18/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is 0.6667.

The rule is that *transparency* combines by multiplication. So if you have two overlapping objects with transparencies of 60% and 33.33%, then the transparency of the overlapping region will be (0.6 × 0.3333) = 0.2.

An object's *alpha* value is equal to 1 minus its transparency, so the combination of α=0.4 and α=0.6667 is equal to 1 - (1-0.4) × (1-0.6667) = 1 - 0.6 × 0.3333 = 1 - 0.2 = 0.8.

By way of illustration, here's an SVG image containing two overlapping circles with alpha values of 0.4 and 0.6667 next to a solid circle filled with 80% black (`#333`):

```html
<svg width="340" height="200" viewBox="0 0 340 200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="80" r="60" fill="#000" opacity="0.4" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="120" r="60" fill="#000" opacity="0.6667" />
  <circle cx="180" cy="100" r="60" fill="#333" opacity="1" />
  <text x="0" y="30">α=0.4</text>
  <text x="0" y="180">α=0.6667</text>
  <text x="250" y="110">80% black</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Makes sense, thanks! Nice comparing against the solid colour, I should've thought of that. Instead of seeing it as 40% opaque, I needed to see it as 60% *transparent*. Then removing 2/3 of that transparency takes me to 80%.